# compactification

Tags: general-topology

What is the advantage when we extend a non-compact space as compact space. For example, one point compactification. I think it makes sense to make a non-complete space as a complete space. However, for one point compactification, we define a new topology. Would you give me any comment for this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The completion of a non-complete space also has a new topology. For example, $Q$ and $R$ and topologically very different, arguably more so than $R$ and its one-point compactification $S^1$.

Comment: Well, a space is homeomorphic to a dense subset of its compactification, so its not like the topological information of the original non-compact space is lost. The benefit of putting our original space inside a compact one is that compactness is very nice - it allows us to take subsequential limits (or limits of a subnet), for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gives the advantage of embedding a space into a compact space.
For example let S be a locally compact Hausdorff space.  Then the
one point compacitification S' of S is a compact Hausdorff space,
hence normal, thus regular.  Since S is a subspace of a regular
space, S is regular.

How would you prove that locally compact Hausdorff spaces
are regular without using a one point compactification?